# What does mean phrase "grizzly statistic"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I run into a phrase - a powerful example of how this grizzly statistic can manifest itself. What in this context means the word grizzly?
Thank you.

Comment: It's a misspelling - ***grizzly*** refers to a type of bear (more rarely, "grey-haired"). The adjective meaning *causing horror or disgust* is spelt [**grisly**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grisly)

Comment: Well, for all we know from the OP, it may be talking about some statistic dealing with grey hair.  But probably not.

Comment: You need to edit to give the context/link/source to the paragraph you found this phrase in.

Comment: I think this is a good question; with the initial misunderstanding of grizzly for grisly, the OP would really have no way to find this out without help.

Comment: @Davo: Your comment prompts me to consciously recognise that if this question had been asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) I wouldn't have closevoted (it would be a valid question, for exactly the reason you give). But here on ELU I think it's reasonable to expect that [linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) would be aware of both words.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Great point. And so I've voted to move it to ELL. :)

Comment: @Davo: I should have done the same myself! But if this question had dragged in ***gristle*** as well (where at first glance ***gristly*** isn't directly related to ***grizzly*** or ***grisly***), I might be much more interested in keeping it here and seeing what one of our *real* experts (not me! :) had to say on the matter.

Comment: I think it's a wonderful malapropism subconsciously derived from the grisly outcome of being mauled by a grizzly. I can't bear any more of this. :-)

Comment: What is the OP?

Comment: This is a link where I found the phrase http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/vegas-shooting-victim-christopher-roybal-facebook-post-shot-death-dead-stephen-paddock-a7980581.html

Comment: @GlebKrylov: Original Poster - you! Regarding the link: and yet again, we lament the disappearance of actual journalists. :(

Comment: Perhaps those statistics really get down to the ***nitty-gritty***. Which I've no idea whether ***gritty*** there has any connection to ***grizzly, grisly, gristly*** (or even to ***grit***).

Answer (score -1):

As the [Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/spelling/grisly-grizzly/) points out:

> *Grizzly* means (1) grayish or flecked with gray, and (2) of or relating to the large brown bear native to western North America. It can also be a noun, short for grizzly bear. *Grisly* means gruesome, ghastly, or inspiring repugnance.
>
> There’s also *gristly,* an adjective used to describe meat with too much cartilage. And there’s *grizzled,* a synonym of grizzly, usually used to describe scruffy-looking older men. *Grizzley* is a misspelling.